# Restrict the access of REST URL's in browser

Tags: spring-mvc, restlet-2.0, appfuse

How to restrict the access of REST urls in browser, can any one please guide me what are the necessary changes to made in security.xml. My web app runs on spring MVC framework.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http pattern="/images/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/styles/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/scripts/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/assets/**" security="none" />


<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/passwordHint*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/requestRecoveryToken*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER, ROLE_PHYSICIAN, ROLE_PRACTICE_STAFF" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/updatePassword*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER, ROLE_PHYSICIAN, ROLE_PRACTICE_STAFF" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/signup*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/practice*" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>   
    <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/app/patientReports*" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/> -->        
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/mediaFile/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER, ROLE_PHYSICIAN, ROLE_PRACTICE_STAFF" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" login-processing-url="/j_security_check" />
    <remember-me user-service-ref="userDao" key="e37f4b31-0c45-11dd-bd0b-0800200c9a66" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDao">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>


<!-- Override the default password-encoder (BCrypt) by uncommenting the following and changing the class -->
<!-- <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/> -->

<global-method-security>
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* *..service.UserManager.getUsers(..))" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* *..service.UserManager.removeUser(..))" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
</global-method-security>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the [Spring security manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-config)?

You need to restrict access to your rest URLs for certain roles. How you get those roles via the users depend on your setup. 
For REST calls you probably don't want form login, but basic authentication.